# Javascript change css code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Javascript code to change the sidebar color with a colorpicker

```
var colorWell;
var defaultColor = "#0078c0";

window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
function startup() {
  colorWell = document.querySelector("#colorWell");
  colorWell.value = defaultColor;
  colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
  colorWell.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
  colorWell.select();
}
function updateFirst(event) {
  var side = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

  if (side) {
    side.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
  }
}function updateAll(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar").forEach(function(side) {
    side.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
  });
}
```

Is there a way that this code also change the css value in the css file?

Comment: You could create the class in css file, and assign this style to the element instead of individually addying style values

`side.classList.add('sideClass')`

`.sideClass{
    background-color: blue;
}`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: No, you can't change your `.css` file content by client javascript code.

Comment: Can you please provide your html code too?

Comment: But, there is a bunch of way how to handle css rules your client side receives from the `.css` file. You can use localStorage, as example, store changes there and use'em

Comment: okay I have something like <div class="sidebar"> and a in the css I have .sidebar {color: blue;} so I can't change the color "blue" with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to have that the user that changed color keep seeing it when returning to the site i will save the color data with `window.localStorage`.

Would be nice to have a working Fiddle

Comment: could you help me out with the code above. I am a bit noob to this xd

Comment: Actually i used this nice and simple tutorial video to learn it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL1F4dCUlLc , i think is more helpful to learn it :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering. Is there a way to reset that color also when you click on a reset button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could ulse :

- [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule), insert rules.
- [deleteRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule), remove rules.

Comment: but does insertRule not only inserting it instead of rewriting it?

Comment: indeed this is why you could use deleteRule() for that